# Customize contents of table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I need a set up the table of content with:

chapters heading as 16pt bold 
sections heading as 14 bold
subsections heading 12pt bold

the rest Chapters (Dedication, Acknowledgment, list of figures) should be 14pt and bold.

I used the package `tocloft` to specify fontsize and boldness, but I want to set up different fontsize and unbold Chapters (Dedication, Acknowledgment, list of figures).

Please check a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[lmargin=3.0cm, rmargin=2.5cm,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm] {geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\newcounter{loopcntr}

\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\fontsize{16}{19}\bfseries\selectfont}
\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{10pt}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\fontsize{14}{17}\bfseries\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\fontsize{12}{14}\bfseries\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\addtocontents{toc}
{\begingroup\protect\renewcommand\protect\cftchapfont{\protect\fontsize{14}{17}\protect\selectfont}}
\listoffigures

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ DEDICATION}
\include{frontmatter/dedication}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ACKNOWLEDGMENT}
\include{frontmatter/acknowledgement}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand*{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ABSTRACT}
\include{frontmatter/abstract}
\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}

\include{chapters/introduction}
\loop\unless\ifnum25<\value{loopcntr}%
\stepcounter{loopcntr}
\chapter{ch\number\value{loopcntr}}

\repeat

\end{document}
```

Regards

Comment: Can you specify what the question is?

Comment: I want to unbold and change the fontsize of chapters (dedication, acknowledgment, list of the figures) in the table of content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend having different font sizes/weights for the ToC -- it does not really look nice, but ...

... it can be achieved by writing the changes to the `ToC` itself, all in a `\begingroup...\endgroup` pair (which must appear in the `ToC` too.) This way the changes act only as long as being inside the group, the 'regular' chapters use the previous definitions.

I also used `tocbibind` (by the same authors as `tocloft`) in order to add the `LoF` to the ToC.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[lmargin=3.0cm, rmargin=2.5cm,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\newcounter{loopcntr}

\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\fontsize{16}{19}\bfseries\selectfont}
\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{10pt}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\fontsize{14}{17}\bfseries\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\fontsize{12}{14}\bfseries\selectfont}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\protect\renewcommand\protect\cftchapfont{\protect\fontsize{14}{17}\protect\selectfont}}
\listoffigures
\chapter{Dedication}
\chapter{Acknowledgement}
\chapter{Abstract}
\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}

\loop\unless\ifnum25<\value{loopcntr}%
\stepcounter{loopcntr}
\chapter{ch\number\value{loopcntr}}

\repeat

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Christian!. I will accept your solution :).

Comment: Hi @Christian. I have an issue with this when I applied to my thesis. It works, but the unbold continues to the chapter one in the Table of content. How can I avoid that?  Thank you.

Comment: @n.a.s: Do you have `\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}` in there as in my example?

Comment: Yes, I added it.

Comment: @n.a.s: Well, as you can see from my answer, it works, if you are using something different I can't see here, it's almost impossible to say what is going wrong for your thesis.

Comment: I used this lines for each chapter between begin and end group: \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{chaptername}
\include{frontmatter/chaptername}

Comment: @nas: That's not really useful information. Especially those dreadful `\include` statements and spaghettification of code. Especially you should not need to add it for each chapter.

Comment: I have checked your example when I include the chapter one from an external .tex file the problem occurs!?

Comment: @n.a.s: Again: Such comments are not useful. I don't know what you have done actually

Comment: I updated my question. I used your code exactly, I only included a chapter called introduction (empty tex file). I want it to be bold but it is not.